# How to store text value element from a cascading list in asp.net Mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im very new to javascript,jquery and ajax. So I have a model:

```
namespace hiophop.Models
{
    public class CarMake
    {
        public class Category
        {
            public int CategoryID { get; set; }
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        }

        public class Product
        {
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a list from the classes and add to them in my controller while passing JSON to the view:

```
namespace hiophop.Controllers
{
    public class CarController : Controller
    {
        List<Category> lstCat = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category() { CategoryID = 1, CategoryName = "Dairy" },
            new Category() { CategoryID = 2, CategoryName = "Meat" },
            new Category() { CategoryID = 3, CategoryName = "Vegetable" }
        };

        List<Product> lstProd = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product() { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "Cheese", CategoryID = 1 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Milk", CategoryID = 1 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Yogurt", CategoryID = 1 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 4, ProductName = "Beef", CategoryID = 2 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 5, ProductName = "Lamb", CategoryID = 2 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 6, ProductName = "Pork", CategoryID = 2 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 7, ProductName = "Broccoli", CategoryID = 3 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 8, ProductName = "Cabbage", CategoryID = 3 },
            new Product() { ProductID = 9, ProductName = "Pepper", CategoryID = 3 }
        };

        public ActionResult GetCategories()
        {
            return Json(lstCat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        public ActionResult GetProducts(int intCatID)
        {

            var products = lstProd.Where(p => p.CategoryID == intCatID);
            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string c ,string p)
        {


            ViewBag.x ="Product:"+ p;
            ViewBag.y = "category" + c;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is were it gets confusing How do I retrieve the text value of the selected list box I am only able to retrieve the Int index for the CategoryId's. I want CategoryName ProductName both strings. Here is my view: The viewbags.x and y only return Ids. Ive tried a few things but Im stuck am I doing something wrong?I left some commented out for you to see what im trying.

```
@model hiophop.Models.CarMake
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CarView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@*<h2>CarView</h2>*@


@ViewBag.y
@ViewBag.x


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Car", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" name="c" class="form-control"></select>
        <label for="product">Product</label>
        <select id="product" name="p"  class="form-control"></select>

        <div id="result"></div>

        <input type="submit" id="Button1" class="btn btn-default" />




    </div>
}
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Get a list of categories and a list of products of the first category.
            $.getJSON('/Car/GetCategories', null, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $('#category').append('<option value=' +
                      this.CategoryID + '>' + this.CategoryName + '</option>');
                });
                $.getJSON('/Car/GetProducts', { intCatID: $('#category').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#product').append('<option value=' +
                          this.ProductID + '>' + this.ProductName + '</option>');

                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error getting products!');
                });
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error getting categories!');
            });

            // Dropdown list change event.
            $('#category').change(function () {
                $('#product option').remove();
                $.getJSON('/Car/GetProducts', { intCatID: $('#category').val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#product').append('<option value=' +
                          this.ProductID + '>' + this.ProductName + '</option>');
                    });
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error getting products!');
                });
            });
        });




        //var result = $('#result');


        //$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button").click(function () {
            var request = $('#category option:selected').text() + "," + $('#product option:selected').text();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/Car/Index',
                            //data: "{'Category':'" + document.getElementById('#category') + "','food':'" + document.getElementById('#product')  + " '}",
                    //        async: false,
                    //        success: function (response) {
                    //            $('#category').val('');
                    //            $('#product').val('');

                    //            alert("record has been saved in database");

                    //        },
                    //        error: function () {
                    //            console.log('there is some error');
                    //        }

                    data: { c: request },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        result.html( '#category: ' + data.CategoryName + '' + '#product' + data.ProductName)
                    }

             });

            });

        //});
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Your code really makes no sense and its not clear what your trying to do. If you wanting to post back the text of each selected options then its `data: { c: $('#category option:selected').text(), p: $('#product option:selected').text(); },`. But your specifying that your return `json` in the ajax call, so your `Index()` post method would throw an exception since your returning html

Comment: Also suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Actually, as I look at your code more, and your description of the problem, I think your problem is even earlier.  Your click even on the button isn't firing, because the ID should be Button1 and not Button, but the form is still submitting because your button is input type=submit, and you created the form with Html.BeginForm().  This causes the form to be submitted to the default action (the same as the get, but as a post instead... that's why it still hits the correct action) but the submitted variables are just the values of the inputs in the form.  To get this working the way you intended, you need to alter the click event for the button (first so that the IDs match, or it will never fire), and then right at the beginning, prevent the normal form submission.  So it should look like this:

```
$('#Button1').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do the rest of the click event handler here
});
```

End Edit

---

You're already getting the correct value with your jquery:

```
$('#category option:selected').text()
```

Would get the selected text for the #category dropdown, rather than the value.  Your problem is that you're building the jquery object as a string and passing it back as the single parameter in your return.  Instead, try this:

```
var postData = {
    c: $('#category option:selected').text(),
    p: $('#product option:selected').text()
};
```

then, in your ajax request:

```
data: postData
```

Also, for what it's worth, there's a much simpler shorthand for this type of ajax request:

```
$.post('/Car/Index', postData).done(function(data) {
    //Do something with the server response here
    result.html( '#category: ' + data.CategoryName + '' + '#product' + data.ProductName)
});
```

Note that success, error, and complete callbacks have been deprecated, and replaced by done(), fail(), and always() respectively.

Edit to address comment:

I'll answer your last question first... Yes!! in a browser (most modern browsers have some version of this) press the f12 key. This should open a developer tools window of some sort.  Look for a tab with javascript stuff in it... in firefox, the tab is called debugger, in chrome it's called sources.  I think it's called debugger in IE too, but I don't remember.  Anyway, on this tab, find the page with your javascript code (if you do it all inline, which is what your example has, it will be the page named the same as your controller action, without an extension).  this should bring up the 'view source' version of the page.  You can set breakpoints in the javascript here, and when the browser gets to them it will break, and you can step through, over, or into just like you would in server side debugging in vs.  You can also set a watch, and monitor the value of variables.

To send the data to the browser in your post, you want to send a JSON object which contains the data.  JSON is just a series of key/value pairs, really.  So a JSON object looks like this:

```
{ "key":"value" }
```

That is a very simple JSON object.  If I were to store that in a variable (for example postData), like this:

```
var postData = { "key":"value" };
```

I could access the value for "key" by saying postData.key, and that would get me "value".  In order to send the data to your controller action, you need to construct a JSON object which has properties that match the parameters that your controller action needs.  In your example, you have two properties on your POST controller action: (string c, string p), So the JSON object you pass in needs to have a property (or KEY) named c, and one named p.  Keep in mind that both javascript AND c# are case-sensitive, so your properties in your JSON object need to match exactly the names of the parameters your controller action wants.

So your controller action needs a JSON object which looks like this:

```
{ "c":"some value", "p":"some other value" }
```

Notice we separate the properties with a comma.. you can put any number in here.  If your controller action has optional parameters, you can leave them out, but if not, they all need to be specified here, or you'll get a 404 error.  So that object above is exactly what your controller wants to see, but the values aren't right obviously, we need to grab those from your select lists.  So to do that, we use the jquery you already had, to get the text from the selected options, and we're left with this:

```
var postData = {
    c: $('#category option:selected').text(),
    p: $('#product option:selected').text()
};
```

Note that when specifying the name of the key, if it doesn't have spaces or anything weird in it, we can omit the quotes.

So now we have a properly formatted JSON object which matches what your controller action wants to receive.  We just need to send this with an ajax post.  Using the type of post you originally had, would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8", This line is not necessary, the browser will figure it out
    url: '/Car/Index',
    data: postData,
    //dataType: 'json', (This line is not necessary, the browser will figure it out
    success: function (data) {
        result.html( '#category: ' + data.CategoryName + '' + '#product' + data.ProductName)
    }
});
```

Note that there are a couple of lines commented out.  They are not necessary for this type of call, the browser is pretty good at figuring out what's needed.

Alternatively, I prefer a shorthand way of specifying posts like this, which I mentioned above, but i'll put it here again:

```
$.post('/Car/Index', postData).done(function(data) {
    result.html( '#category: ' + data.CategoryName + '' + '#product' + data.ProductName)
});
```

This does exactly the same thing is the $.ajax version above, but it's much simpler, in my opinion.

I hope that clears it up!  I'm happy to answer any more questions, or provide any additional clarification.

Comment: Thank you I am kind of confused about how I would I pass the data to the controller in post..Thank you so much for your response it helps a lot. Its not working as I want tho. I will study your code more. Is there a way to debug ajax or see if the data is being passed?

Comment: You're very welcome.  My answers to your questions are too long for a comment, so i'll edit my answer to address them.